# Votes on "Hot Meta Posts" have low contrast

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

At the "Hot Meta Posts" area, you can see how many votes the popular question have.

[Main](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site:
[image: main]

But at meta, the contrast is very low and the numbers are near invisible:
[image: meta]

Comment: The designers have been given the bat signal; they'll fix it up tomorrow.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Any update on this fix?

Comment: @Alex fixed - again, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed both the question scores and section headers to have a much lighter font color; the fix will be pushed out in the next few hours.

Sorry for the delay on this.